# Failed to import transformers.training_args because of the following error - failed to map segment from shared object - Lambda and Docker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, huggingface-transformers

I'm currently working on a Lambda project that downloads models from my own huggingface repo and then does some inference on it. I bundle a Docker image into ECR and invoke my lambda function using apigateway. The apigateway part and the ECR part works fine, but I'm having trouble with the actual lambda function. Whenever I invoke my function, I get this in return:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Failed to import transformers.training_args because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):\n/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nvidia/cufft/lib/libcufft.so.10: failed to map segment from shared object",
    "errorType": "RuntimeError",
    "requestId": "",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py\", line 126, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1204, in _gcd_import\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1176, in _find_and_load\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 690, in _load_unlocked\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 940, in exec_module\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    from model import generator, get_model\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/model.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer\n",
        "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1229, in _handle_fromlist\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py\", line 1116, in __getattr__\n    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py\", line 1128, in _get_module\n    raise RuntimeError(\n"
    ]
}
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Copy function code
COPY *.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda.handler" ]
```

`Requirements.txt`:

```
datasets==2.11.0
aiohttp==3.8.4
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
lyricsgenius==3.0.1
numpy==1.23.5
requests==2.28.2
transformers==4.27.4
huggingface-hub==0.13.4
python-dotenv==1.0.0
torch==2.0.0
```

This is the tutorial I followed to create and push my Docker stuff: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html.

Thanks